# How to check if Elasticsearch service is running using Search::Elasticsearch

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I am using the following statement to connect to Elasticsearch server:

```
use Search::Elasticsearch;
 
# Connect to localhost:9200:
 
my $e = Search::Elasticsearch->new();
```

Is there a way to check if Elasticsearch service is alive and kicking using this module?  Also, if it is running on a remote server, how do we check that the service is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `ping()` method that you can use for this. It tries to talk to a node in the cluster:

```
$e->ping or die "can't talk to ES";
```

Or you can get your `Search::Elasticsearch` instance to call Cluster API endpoints, which will return more detailed info, e.g.:

```
my $response = $e->cluster->health();
# examine response
```